# reactjs onchangevent and keypress event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Encountered a problem in react. There area two input `Textfield` in the same row with labels (A, B) having an initial `null` value. Then how we can achieve this?

- if the user inputs value in text field "A", the values of text field B should be automatically zero
- and then vice versa

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `onChange event` and `useState` hook. in the below example, I defined a `onChange event` where I set A and B with what you typed and zero respectively.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState();
  const [b, setB] = useState();

  function AKeyPress(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setB("0");
    setA(e.target.value);
  }

  function BKeyPress(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setA("0");
    setB(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header"></header>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      A <input type="text" onChange={AKeyPress} value={a} />
      B <input type="text" onChange={BKeyPress} value={b} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the values in state and if any of these changes, set the current one to the updated value, and delete the other one. You can use the `onChange` event to track changes and the `event.target` to get the field value.

Check out the example below:

```js
function App() {
  const [field1, setField1] = React.useState('');
  const [field2, setField2] = React.useState('');

  function handleChange(event) {
    if (event.target.name === 'field1') {
      setField2('');
      setField1(event.target.value);
    }
    if (event.target.name === 'field2') {
      setField1('');
      setField2(event.target.value);
    }
  }

  return (
    <form>
      <label>
        Field 1
        <input
          type="text"
          name="field1"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={field1}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        Field 2
        <input
          type="text"
          name="field2"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={field2}
        />
      </label>
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

You could also use an array as the state:

```js
function App() {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = React.useState([{
    id: 'input1',
    value: '',
  }, {
    id: 'input2',
    value: '',
  }]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    let updatedInputs = inputs.map((input) =>
      input.id === event.target.name
        ? { ...input, value: event.target.value }
        : { ...input, value: '' }
    );
    setInputs(updatedInputs);
  }

  return (
    <form>
      {inputs.map((input) => (
        <label key={input.id}>
          {input.id}
          <input
            type="text"
            name={input.id}
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={input.value}
          />
        </label>
      ))}
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```